# When I recover a mysql table use binlog it errored

Tags: mysql

I use `truncate` delete a table
but I want to recovery the data use binlog.
Then it occurs error, the error massage shows as : **"the binlog statement of type table_map was not preceded by a format description binlog statement"** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can't get data after truncate a table as truncate statement first drop the table (keeping same copy) and then create same structure which is fast process to delete all data but it is not like delete which keep statement in binlog.

But if you created this table recently suppose 5 days before and you are keeping more than 5 days binlogs then you can try to filter all statements related with this table till just before truncate command and then you can replay these statements on your server.

Answer (score 0):

`/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog --database=bbs --start-date="2016-03-20 00:00:00"  --stop-date="2016-03-21 9:00:00" /mysql/data/mysql-bin.000071 > bbs.sql`

//if there are other binlogs，then add them to bbs.sql

`/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog --database=bbs --start-date="2016-03-20 00:00:00"  --stop-date="2016-03-21 9:00:00" /mysql/data/mysql-bin.000072 >> bbs.sql`

`cat bbs.sql | grep 'comment' > comment.sql`

//delete the truncate sql

`vim comment.sql`

//excute the sql

`mysql> source comment.sql`